# Error installing Pythonnet 2.3.0 in Windows 10 and Python 3.11

Tags: python, .net, python.net

I'm trying to install Pythonnet on Python 3.11.5, but I'm getting this error:

```
Collecting pythonnet==2.3.0
  Using cached pythonnet-2.3.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: pythonnet
  Building wheel for pythonnet (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pythonnet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for pythonnet
Failed to build pythonnet
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [100 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Comprobando actualizaciones desde https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
      Se est  ejecutando NuGet.exe 3.5.0.
      Actualizando NuGet.exe a 6.7.0.
      Actualizaci¢n correcta.
      Detecci¢n autom tica de MSBuild: se usar  la versi¢n de msbuild "16.11.2.50704" de "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin".
      Restoring NuGet package NUnit.3.6.0.
      Restoring NuGet package NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.0.
      Restoring NuGet package UnmanagedExports.1.2.7.
      Adding package 'NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.0' to folder 'C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\packages'
      Adding package 'NUnit.3.6.0' to folder 'C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\packages'
      Adding package 'UnmanagedExports.1.2.7' to folder 'C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\packages'
      Added package 'UnmanagedExports.1.2.7' to folder 'C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\packages'
      Added package 'NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.0' to folder 'C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\packages'
      Added package 'NUnit.3.6.0' to folder 'C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\packages'
      
      Archivos de NuGet Config usados:
          C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
          C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config
      
      Fuentes usadas:
          C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\.nuget\packages\
          https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
      
      Instalado:
          3 paquetes(s) en packages.config projects
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 292, in <module>
          sys.exit(main())
                   ^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 272, in main
          python_h = preprocess_python_headers()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 192, in preprocess_python_headers
          for line in _check_output(cmd).splitlines():
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 41, in _check_output
          output = subprocess.check_output(*args, **kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\setup.py", line 366, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 346, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 466, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 492, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0xvuhhsu\pythonnet_d7729095017d40dcafba144d8df27907\setup.py", line 191, in build_extension
          subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, geninterop, interop_file])
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\josemaria.garcia\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe', 'tools\\geninterop\\geninterop.py', 'src\\runtime\\interop311.cs']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pythonnet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pythonnet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I could install `pythonnet 3.0.2` so I wonder if it's some sort of incompatibility with Python 3.11 (although according to its [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/), I'm between 3.7 and 3.12 so I'm safe (I guess?). I tried installing it on 3.10.9, but I got the same error. And pythonnet 3.0.2 works only partially for my use case, which is this, for context:

```
import clr.AddReference(R'C:\Users\josemaria.garcia\Documents\XXXXX\XXXXX.dll')
from OwnedLibrary import QuickLZ

quickLZRunner = QuickLZ()
z = b'String de bytes'
quickLZRunner.compress(z)
```

This code should work (or it worked for `pythonnet 2.3.0` and an older Python version) but the methods in the class QuickLZ are not there (and they are there when I inspect the file that generated the DLL file in Visual Studio).