# Pythonnet not able to import DLL because RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata not found

Tags: python, c#, dll, dllimport, python.net

I'm using Python 3.11.5 and Pythonnet 3.0.2 to import a DLL provided by my company to run some C# functions in a Python environment.

I was provided a script that would just do this:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(R'C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\XXXX\OwnledLibrary.dll')
from OwnedPackage.Compression import QuickLZ
my_instance = QuickLZ()
# Everything is ready for use now
```

However, this way the library is imported **without its static methods** (which, in this case, it's all of them that are not "default", such as `Equals`, `GetType`, etc.).

```
 #Output from dir(QuickLZ) 
 ['Equals',
 'Finalize',
 'GetHashCode',
 'GetType',
 'MemberwiseClone',
 'Overloads',
 'ReferenceEquals',
 'ToString',
 '__class__',
.... ]
```

Assuming this is caused by an issue with the versions (the script I was given was written for `pythonnet 2.3.0`, a version I cannot install because of an error I haven't found anything about, and I invite you to [give it a go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188812/error-installing-pythonnet-2-3-0-in-windows-10-and-python-3-11) if you know anything about it, and an older version of Python), I read the documentation of `pythonnet` and tried to update said script.

```
from pythonnet import load
load('netfx')
import clr
clr.AddReference(R'C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\XXX\OwnedLibrary.dll')

>>>>from OwnedPackage.Compression import QuickLZ
```

Now I get an error in the highlighted line which says that `RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata` hasn't been found.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\HarshMoP\prueba.py", line 6, in <module>
    from OwnedPackage.Compression import QuickLZ
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1229, in _handle_fromlist
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado '**RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata**, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8f52d83c1a22df51' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
Nombre de archivo: 'RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8f52d83c1a22df51'
   en System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)  
   en System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   en System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   en System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   en System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   en System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element, Type type, Boolean inherit)
   en System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(MemberInfo element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   en System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute[T](MemberInfo element, Boolean inherit)
   en Python.Runtime.MethodObject.AllowThreads(MethodBase[] methods)
   en Python.Runtime.ClassManager.GetClassInfo(Type type, ClassBase impl)
   en Python.Runtime.ClassManager.InitClassBase(Type type, ClassBase impl, ReflectedClrType pyType)
   en Python.Runtime.ReflectedClrType.GetOrCreate(Type type)
   en Python.Runtime.ModuleObject.GetAttribute(String name, Boolean guess)
   en Python.Runtime.ModuleObject.tp_getattro(BorrowedReference ob, BorrowedReference key)

AVS: El registro del enlace de ensamblado está desactivado.
Para habilitar el registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado, establezca el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) como 1.
Nota: existe una disminución del rendimiento asociada registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado.
Para desactivar esta característica, elimine el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Make sure that the RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata assembly is installed on your computer. You can download the assembly using `dotnet add package UnmanagedExports`